# Ignore default collider but not the trigger collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following on my `Awake` method:

```
void Awake() {
    Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(LayerMask.NameToLayer("Player"), LayerMask.NameToLayer("Weapon"));
}
```

On the object I have two colliders, where one is a trigger and the other is a default collider. What I would like to do is allow my player layer to ignore my weapons `default collider`, but not ignore the weapons `trigger collider`.

Is there a good way to do this? Because my above code is making it ignore both colliders.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can ignore it in your OnCollisionEnter function manually, this is an easier way to do it.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
    //ignore collider of Player
    if(!other.transform.name.Equals("Player")
    {
        //do something here
    }

}

void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
    // Don't ignore trigger of Player

    //do something here
}
```

Comment: and why? this won't work not enough to improve answer

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are disabling the collisions between those 2 layers you disable everything. I cant test this now, but have you tried creating a cube, make it trigger and name the layer "TriggerLayer", and of course drag the cube to the wepon so it acts like its child. They would be on the same parent but have different layers. Im not sure if this works, or if it is a good solution, but give it a try.